# MATLAB equivalent in c++

Tags: c++, matlab

In MATLAB inorder to access the odd or even rows and columns of a matrix we use

```
A = M(1:2:end,1:2:end);
```

Is there an equivalent for this in C++? or How do i do this in C++.

Basically what i want to do is in matlab i have

```
A(1:2:end,1:2:end) = B(1:2:end,:);
A(2:2:end,2:2:end) = B(2:2:end,:);
```

I want to implement the same in C++

Comment: You need to iterate over. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ the `for` loop is constructed as follows

```
for (initial state; condition for termination; increment)
```

So if you are looking for the odd elements, you can:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += 2),
```

whereas if you are looking for the even elements:

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i += 2).
```

Where `size` depends if you are looping through the rows or columns. Take into account that because C++ arrays start at index 0, your odd elements will correspond to even indexes and your even elements will correspond to odd indexes.

Now, the answer: If you want to get the elements of a matrix, in C++ you must loop through the matrix with a `for` loop. You can modify the elements you access by modifying the *increment* property of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is available only in a fairly obscure class, `std::valarray`. You need a `std::gslice`  (Generalized slice) with stride {2,2} to access the `std::valarray`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i= 0; i < rows/2; i++)
  for(int j= 0; j < columns/2; j++)
    A[i][j] = M[i*2][j*2];
```

Comment: This code will access memory outside the allocated array.